# Paging library 3. No load more data

Tags: android, paging

Why Recycler load only 15 items and no more? I do all by manual page in android.com
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data
What I do wrong? Please help.
I write this simple code to understand Paging library 3. I want endless list. On library 2 i do it, but now it deprecate.

My RxPagingSource

```
public class SaleJournalSource extends RxPagingSource<String, SaleJournalItem> {
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public String getRefreshKey(@NonNull PagingState<String, SaleJournalItem> pagingState) {
      return null;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Single<LoadResult<String, SaleJournalItem>> loadSingle(@NonNull LoadParams<String> loadParams) {

      Single<List<SaleJournalItem>> single = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
         List<SaleJournalItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            SaleJournalItem s1 = new SaleJournalItem();
            s1.name = "1";
            list.add(s1);
         }
         return list;
      });


      return single
              .delay(1, SECONDS)
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .map(this::xx);
   }

   public LoadResult<String, SaleJournalItem> xx(List<SaleJournalItem> list) {
      return new LoadResult.Page<>(
              list,
              null,
              String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()),
              LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED,
              LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED);
   }
```

My Activity onCreate

```
SaleJournalViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SaleJournalViewModel.class);
viewModel.init();

adapter = new SaleJournalAdapter(new SaleJournalAdapter.dif());

binding.recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
binding.recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

viewModel.flowable
        .to(autoDisposable(AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider.from(this)))
        .subscribe(data -> adapter.submitData(getLifecycle(), data));
```

My ViewModel

```
public class SaleJournalViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public Flowable<PagingData<SaleJournalItem>> flowable;

    public void init() {

        CoroutineScope viewModelScope = ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(this);

        SaleJournalSourceFactory saleJournalSourceFactory = new SaleJournalSourceFactory();

        Pager<String, SaleJournalItem> pager = new Pager<>(
                new PagingConfig(20, 10),
                saleJournalSourceFactory::get);

        flowable = PagingRx.getFlowable(pager);
        PagingRx.cachedIn(flowable, viewModelScope);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

in my test i don't call getItem() in adapter onBinding, that's why i got only items < prefetchDistance.

I hope this help someone. I waste 1 day on it (